# Can Servicestack Deserialize XML without namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, servicestack

I'm familiar with these two methods:

```
var newDataSet = XmlSerializer.DeserializeFromString<NEWDATASET>(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
var newDataSet = xmlDoc.OuterXml.FromXml<NEWDATASET>();
```

But they both give me the same error:

> DeserializeDataContract: Error converting type: Error in line 1
>   position 40. Expecting element 'NEWDATASET' from namespace
>   ''.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'NEWDATASET',
>   namespace ''.

I feel like there should be a way to get this to work as long as the the element names either match the public property names or the `DataMemberAttribute` Name parameter of the public property was set to the element name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't have it's own XML Serializer, it's `DataContractSerializer` uses .NET's XML DataContract and its `XmlSerializer` uses .NET's XmlSerializer. So the XML payload would need to be deserialized from either of those BCL implementations.

An alternative way to parse arbitrary XML is to use XLinq and ServiceStack's [XLinqExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/XLinqExtensions.cs) which provide UX-friendly helpers to simplify XML parsing.

Here are some examples for parsing arbitrary XML with XLinq and helpers:

- [XlinqExtensionsTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Xlinq/XlinqExtensionsTests.cs)
- [Parsing Razor Namespaces from Web.config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/aa66cc370a1af883d83c61fa3f79abdf353f784d/src/ServiceStack/Platforms/PlatformNet.HostConfig.cs#L34)
- [Parsing RSA Private Key](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/CryptUtils.cs#L535)